# pip.iniの設定でproxyを通過する方法

Tags: windows-10, pip, proxy

### 事象

社内Proxyを経由する関係上、proxyの設定が必要であった。
pip.iniファイルでの設定では、proxyを通過できなかったが、環境変数の設定では通過ができた。
この事象について、ご存知であれば理由をご教示ください。
また、iniファイルのproxy設定で通過できる方法があれば、併せてご教示ください。

### やりたいこと

pip.iniファイルでのプロキシ定義にて環境構築を行いたい。

### 環境

OS:Windows 10 Pro (64bit)
Python:3.10.4
pip:22.0.4
proxy設定：ユーザIDとパスワードが必要な環境

### やったこと

前提：
`set HTTP_PROXY = http://UID:PASS@proxy:port`のコマンド実行後、`pip install <pkg>`は動作する

1. pip.iniファイルを%appdata%\pipフォルダに格納し、`pip install <pkg>`を実行
   ※`pip config list`により、pip.iniを読み込めていることを確認
2. pip.iniファイルをプロジェクトの仮想環境配下に格納し、`pip install <pkg>`を実行
   ※`pip config list`により、pip.iniを読み込めていることを確認
3. パスワードに特殊文字が含まれるため、パーセントエンコーディングをしたものを設定していたが、`\`によるエスケープに変更  ⇒NG

Comment: 参考: [How to configure PIP per config file to use a proxy (with authentification)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43473041)

Comment: pip..ini はどのように記載し、どこに保存したかの情報も質問に含めておくと回答が付きやすいかもしれません。

Comment: @cubick ご指摘ありがとうございます。
追記いたしました。